# django postgres conditional constrain

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to set a conditional unique constrain to one of my model field (column on db perspective) with respect to another boolean field but can't find a way to do it.

I'm creating a web management tool, to aid/control custumers atendance, based on numbered cards while they are still on the store.
My main objective is to **prevent my user to save** an card number **while** this number is still active (aka **boolean field)** with another custumer.
Something like this on models.py:

```
    class Cards(models.Model):
         card_number = models.PositiveIntegerField("""{{RESTRICTION NEEDED}}""")
         card_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
         custumer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
         status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

maybe something like this would work directly on postgres, didn't tried yet

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX card_number_ind ON Cards (card_number) WHERE (status is False);
```

Any chance to do it directly with Django? I mean set a conditional unique constrain with respect to a boolean field (status) on Django?

TIA
Obs.This is my first question ever on stackoverflow, feel free to criticize on style.

Comment: You shouldn't do this in models.py, you should separate logic and data as much as you can. Do you use a form or something to save a card number?

Comment: You may modify save() method or set a model validation (if you are using a form) for checking the status.

Comment: @Shang Wang It's not really logic though- the database schema should correctly model the data. Just as you would want to ensure certain columns are unique in a regular database (e.g. user's email), in Felicio's case, card_number should be unique where status is False. With the constraint, it guarantees that the database will never have identical card_number where status is False.

Comment: @ShangWang Yup, form it is. I'll try Derek's solutions and report afterwards.

Comment: Yup, Derek's solution meets the restriction I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django doesn't support defining conditional constraints in models.py, however you can create a migration to add such a constraint.

Start by creating an empty migration

```
./manage.py makemigrations appname --empty
```

This will create an empty migration file. Next, you'll want to add your custom constraint to the migration

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    ... 

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('create unique index card_number_ind on cards (card_number) where (status is false)'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting in [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/) there is now a `UniqueConstraint` declaration available that has a `condition` option.

**condition**

**UniqueConstraint.condition**

A **Q** object that specifies the condition you want the constraint to enforce.

For example:

```
UniqueConstraint(fields=['user'], condition=Q(status='DRAFT'), name='unique_draft_user')
```

ensures that each user only has one draft.

Comment: is it available for non unique cases ? Like i want to make a field required when a certain value is there in another field.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Yes, you can create complex constraints as well.  You also may be interested in django -pgtriggers.